# Realm losing data in ignored property variable inside sub object? (swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm building an object that stores a `List<Int>` (which Realm now handles in version 3+) and I want to be able to do a fast lookup, so am also keeping a dictionary of type `[Int: Int]` populated as I add items into the list.

Realm obviously can't store the dictionary, but it can store the List. This pattern works fine when I use it in my main object, but when I put it into an object that's referenced by the main Top object, the dictionary keeps getting reset to empty. To test this I created a simple project that only has a single View Controller, and the only thing it does is create the realm, create a main object, and add some items into a list in the sub-object, and print out the result (all in the viewDidLoad method).

Sample code that demonstrates the issue:

```
@objcMembers class Top: Object {
    dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var inside: Inside? = Inside()

    func addInside(_ value: Int) {
        inside?.add(value)
    }
}

@objcMembers class Inside: Object {
    var name = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var list = List<Int>()
    var dictionary = [Int: Int]()

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] { return ["dictionary", "name"] }

    func add(_ value: Int) {
        list.append(value)
        dictionary[value] = value
        print("Name: \(name); Dictionary: \(dictionary); List: \(list)")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.deleteAll()
    }

    let topObj = Top()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(topObj)
        topObj.addInside(12)
        topObj.addInside(32)
        topObj.addInside(42)
    }
}
```

The output of this in the console shows:

```
Name: 977DBC69-BEAA-4F33-BB38-60643DFEA72D; Dictionary: [12: 12]; List: List<int> <0x604000102f40> (
    [0] 12
)
Name: 4EB8F28E-0401-4CB7-9E77-A9F769EFAC64; Dictionary: [32: 32]; List: List<int> <0x600000103f90> (
    [0] 12,
    [1] 32
)
Name: 453608E0-2DEA-4D43-AF73-929137D8E16A; Dictionary: [42: 42]; List: List<int> <0x600000104020> (
    [0] 12,
    [1] 32,
    [2] 42
)
```

I added the UUID string into the Inside class and made it a non managed property also to see if it was merely a problem with Dictionary; but both have issues. This example shows that Realm is creating a new instance of the object every time I call a method on it - although I would expect the object to remain in memory because I am still referencing the Top object that holds it.

Is there a configuration that will tell Realm to stop creating new instances of the sub object in these simple cases? If I had reloaded the original Top object from the db I'd expect to have lost those ignored properties, but this just doesn't make sense to me. What else am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `This example shows that Realm is creating a new instance of the object every time I call a method on it ` yup that's how managed Results works, it doesn't cache a thing

Comment: I didn’t see that same behavior when I had the same setup in the Top object though - that’s why it surprised me.  So every ignored property needs to be a calculated one?